# EJB3 / JSF2: Design of JSF2 app with ConversationalScope and Stateful EJB

Tags: jsf-2, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6

My use case is as follows:

Managing orders with order lines, a customer and payment details.

The app consists of an order list view from which an order detail view can be opened for editing an existing order or creating an new order. The order detail view uses a view param (existing order id or nothing to indicate a new order to be created).

When the order detail view is opened an OrderControllerBean is starting a ConversationalScope and depending on the availability of the order id loading or creating a new order entity. This bean is a stateful session bean as well meant to be used as a facade. The bean contains methods for handling order lines, the customer and the payment details as well as saving and deleting an order. These methods use injected EJBs which are designed as stateless session beans as some kind of DAOs to handle the JPA entities order, order line, customer and payment detail.

From the order detail view with customer info, payment info and order line list the user can navigate to the order line detail view adding/editing order lines and to the customer and payment detail view in a similar manner. Those detail views all use the same OrderControllerBean. On the customer, order line and payment detail views there are Ok and Cancel buttons which are not transactional.

On the order detail view there is a Save and Cancel button which should persist all modifications which are done during the conversation.

The question i have now is: is this design suitable and ok?

I am not sure about the following issues:

What happens if the user never use Save or Cancel?

Does everything stay around till the conversion or the session times out?
What does this mean from the transaction perspective?
What does this mean for the managed entities? 
What happens if the user leaves his worksplace and comes back later continuing work on the conversation? If the conversation is timed out, how can i gracefully handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Stateful beans are a pain and a source of problems in my opinion.

It's better if you handle timeouts at the http session level, rather than givin this responsibility to the Application server (specially since the http session timeout is still relevant you just add another timeout)

You can replace the persitent state provided by the stateful bean with some kind of object caching or if you prefer you can add a sessionid to the database and keep track of your objects states there (it can be special tables to hold temporary objects until saved or discarded for example).

All in all, keep things apart, timeout and temporary objects on the web server side, and use the ejbs for persistence (JPA) and as a facade (stateless beans)

Comment: whats then all about the ConversionalScope and stateful session beans? If they seem to be useless and we have to implement all the state keeping for ourself?

Comment: Bad experiences with them may color my judgement, one thing is exposing a single entry point to business logic, and another thing is adding the state keeping responsibility to the ejb layer. I prefer the business operations to be as atomic as they can. But once again, i had serveral bad experiences with stateful ejbs mostly with websphere so ymmv

Comment: well, i am new in this field and lack experience. So far i have no bad experience with conversional scope, the only issue i had was loosing persistence context when i only used stateless session beans and got detached entities. Thats why i want to switch to stateful session beans for the facade, eg. OrderControllerBean.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to evaluate the either/or situation in creating orders? There should simply be a button that says : **New Order** that launches a popup form and another, possibly from a datatable row that says "View Order Details".
The design is fine. Just a few tweaks.

1. You'll want to create and maintain a single session scoped object(call it `Visit`) in which you store all session related material. I'd advise you stick with the JSF session scoped bean that is dependent on the http session and can be effectively managed by the container. JSF Session Scoped beans are stored as simple objects in the http session and so can be easily manipulated outside the context of JSF. CDI Session Scoped beans however are trickier to handle outside of CDI.
2. I'll also advise you break up your order creation process into a multi-step process using dynamically loaded page fragments `<ui:include/>` or the fine **primefaces wizard** component. With a multi-step creation, all you need to do is gather data along the steps and only commit a transaction when you've all the info you need from all the steps in a DTO. Keep the wizard DTO in the single session object so the container can cleanup in case of a timeout. If the user never saves or cancel or walks away from his desk, the session will die a natural death. And he can come back and continue his transaction if he makes it in time. Not sure what carlos has against **stateless session beans but in my experience, they're a nice way of exposing business processes, in that they can expose their functionality in other ways like webservices and message targets** (JEE5). **Above all, it's very good design to keep as much business processing out of the managed beans as possible and into durable constructs like EJBs and Spring beans etc.**

Comment: i dont understand your question with the either/or situation. On the order list view which is basically a datatable there is a New Order button on the right most columns header and a Edit Order button on the right most rows column. Just the order details view behind is the same...
ad 1) And i am not sure how a session scoped bean can help. Thats why i want to use conversional scope. When i start to edit an order, new or existing, the conversion should start and when i finish, cancel or save, the conversion should end. Or is something conceptually wrong with it?

Comment: ad 2) as this order creation is part of an bigger erp system and not only a simple web shop where a user needs to be guided through a wizard or the user will not do any other tasks besides the order creation i prefer the classical rich client design, where a user works with a central view and from it he opens "sub" views to perform some tasks and he then come back to the central view to save all his work. And i think the conversational scope and a stateful session bean is exactly meant to be the tooling for such things. Or i am wrong? And Carlos has concerns about stateful session beans...